# Implementing structure from other header file

Tags: c++, struct, header, extern

I have to have a structure "configset" in a class-header, something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    static configset *getnext();
}
```

Of course the compiler complains that configset isn't a type, but it is implemented in another header-file, along with some functions. Because of that I can't just include that header-file, the compiler would throw errors that these functions are defined multiple times. But how can I get the configset in my class-header? Just copying won't work also, since the compiler throws then an error that the structure was defined twice.

Comment: including a file multiple times should be fine.  If the compiler is saying that the functions are defined multiple times, that means your header is poorly designed.  (A) move the function _defintitions_ (not declarations) to a cpp file, or (B) mark the functions as `inline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declare `configset` or declare your functions that are defined in a header file as `inline`.

Comment: Forward declaration was just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **forward declaration** like so:

```
// Forward declare configset. Tells compiler that the class/struct is defined in 
// another translation unit
struct configset;

class A {
public:
    static configset *getnext();
};
```

Note that this only works as long as you only use pointers to configset.

Answer (score 1):

Move the implementation of the `configset` methods into a separate .cpp (not header) file.